# Why are there Conda specific Docker images when Conda is not an OS?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

My understanding is that Docker environments are essentially stripped down Linux operating systems.  So why is there an [Anaconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) Docker image when Anaconda is not an operating system - given that Conda / Anaconda is used *within* a Linux distribution.

Comment: For the same reason there exist Docker images for other languages and frameworks: so people can build containerized services on top of that platform.

Comment: Right but having say a "Python" Docker image is incorrect.  Python needs to be installed on an operating system - right? It can't just run by itself.

Comment: The Conda image is really no different in concept than the existing Python image: they are both built on top of a Debian userspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong to use a software containerization tool to containerize... well, software.

The existence of Conda-specific Docker images should not be seen as invalid just because Conda is not an OS. It's as valid as [Python Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), or, say, [Jenkins Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/).

That's because the motivation of creating a Docker is plain and simple: to package **software** someone wants to run somewhere.

Don't just trust my word - see what [Docker has to say](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container). From their own definition in "What is a Container?", they say "A standardized unit of **software**". It doesn't say "A standardized unit of Operating Systems", so it's not safe to conclude the only task or restriction relating Docker images is their OSes.

As for Conda, for example, the benefits it brings to Python environment management is both scriptable and useful for Python services you'll want to build and manage once inside a Docker image. Perhaps your *specific* workflow notions don't match that use case, but software in its essence is extremely bendable. You can assume there's a considerable number of people that benefit from it.